# How to join with unknown condition like pivot in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, backend

I have the following code to

```
public function get_posted_questions($data) {

    include dirname(__FILE__) . "/database.php";
    $user_db_name = $dbconfig[$data['college_id']]['database'];

    if (isset($data['start'])) {
        $start = $data['start'];
    } else {
        $start = 0;
    }
    if (isset($data['end']) and ! empty($data['end'])) {
        $end = $data['end'];
    } else {
        $end = 30;
    }

    /*
     * multiple college database funda here goes
     */
    $max_college_id = "
        SELECT DISTINCT college_id
        FROM just_ask_question
        WHERE
            status = '1'
            AND isDeleted = '0'
            AND college_id !='0'
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT $start, $end
    ";
    $max_college_id_run = mysql_query($max_college_id);



    $question_data = array();
    $question_query = "
        SELECT
            Q.id,
            Q.title,
            Q.description,
            Q.user_id,
            Q.college_id,
            Q.datetime,
            IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT T.name),'') AS tags,
            IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(' ',U.firstName,U.lastName),'') AS user_name
            IFNULL(U.image,'') AS image,
            IFNULL(V.id,'') AS no_of_view,
            IFNULL(Vote.upvote,'') AS up_vote,
            IFNULL(answer.id,0) AS no_of_answer,
            IFNULL(is_upvote,0) AS upvote_status,
            category_name
        FROM just_ask_question AS Q 
        LEFT JOIN just_ask_question_tag Qt
            ON Qt.question_id = Q.id 
        LEFT JOIN just_ask_tag T
            ON T.id = Qt.tag_id 
        LEFT JOIN just_ask_category 
            ON just_ask_category.id = Q.category_id
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT COUNT(id) as id, question_id FROM just_ask_answer
            ) AS answer ON answer.question_id = Q.id
    ";

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($max_college_id_run) ) {
        $user_db_name = $dbconfig[$row['college_id']]['database'];
        $question_query .= "
            CASE WHEN Q.college_id = '".$row['college_id']."'
                THEN LEFT JOIN $user_db_name.users U ON U.id = Q.user_id
        ";
    }

    $question_query .= "
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT count(id) AS id, question_id FROM just_ask_view
            ) AS V ON V.question_id = Q.id
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(upvote) as upvote,
                    question_id
                FROM just_ask_upvote_downvote
                WHERE upvote = '1' AND is_question = '1'
                GROUP BY question_id
            ) AS Vote 
            ON Vote.question_id = Q.id 
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    IF(COUNT(id) > 0,1,0) AS is_upvote,
                    question_id
                FROM just_ask_upvote_downvote
                WHERE
                    upvote = '1'
                    AND college_id = '" . $data['college_id'] . "'
                    AND user_id = '" . $data['user_id'] . "'
                    AND is_question = '1'
            ) AS Is_Vote
            ON Is_Vote.question_id = Q.id
        WHERE
            Q.status = '1'
            AND Q.isDeleted = '0'
            AND CASE
                WHEN Q.visibility = 0 AND Q.college_id != 0 THEN Q.college_id = '" . $data['college_id'] . "'
                ELSE true
                END
    ";




    if (!empty($data['search_text'])) {
        $search_text = $data['search_text'];
        $question_query .= " and (Q.title like '%$search_text%' or Q.description like '%$search_text%' or T.name like '%$search_text%')";
    }

    $question_query .= " group by Q.id order by Q.id desc limit $start,$end";

    $question_query_run = mysql_query($question_query);

    /* get weather question exist */
    $check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($question_query_run);
    if ($check_num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question_query_run)) {
            if ($row['image'] != '') {
                $row['thumbnail'] = USER_THUMBNAIL_URL . $row['image'];
                $row['image'] = IMAGE_URL . $row['image'];
            } else
                $row['thumbnail'] = '';
            $question_data[] = $row;
        }
        $status['statuscode'] = "1";
        $status['statusmessage'] = "ok";
        $status['question_data'] = $question_data;
        $response['response'] = $status;
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }else {
        $status['statuscode'] = "2";
        $status['statusmessage'] = "There is no record found";
        $response['response'] = $status;
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }
}
```

AND the db config file like which contain the database name information 
like

```
    $dbconfig['1'] = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user_name' => 'root',
        'password' => 'test123*',
        'database' => 'staging_myuniversity'
    );


$dbconfig['2'] = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user_name' => 'root',
        'password' => 'test123*',
        'database' => 'staging_myuniversity_dias'
);
```

the database are reside on same server and with full permission.

the query generate like this

```
select  Q.id,Q.title,Q.description,Q.user_id,Q.college_id,
       Q.datetime,
       ifnull(group_concat(distinct T.name),'') as tags,
       ifnull(CONCAT_WS(' ',
                       U.firstName,U.lastName),'') as user_name,
       ifnull(U.image,
               '') as image,ifnull(V.id,'') as no_of_view,
       ifnull(Vote.upvote,
               '') as up_vote,
       ifnull(answer.id,0) as no_of_answer,
       ifnull(is_upvote,
               0
             ) as upvote_status,
       category_name
    from  just_ask_question as Q
    left join  just_ask_question_tag Qt on Qt.question_id = Q.id
    left join  just_ask_tag T on T.id = Qt.tag_id
    left join  just_ask_category on just_ask_category.id = Q.category_id
    left join  
      ( SELECT  count(id) as id,question_id
            from  just_ask_answer
      ) as answer on answer.question_id = Q.id case when Q.college_id = '1' then
    left join  staging_myuniversity.users U on U.id = Q.user_id case when Q.college_id = '12'then
    left join  campify_solutions_mathura.users U on U.id = Q.user_id case when Q.college_id = '4' then
    left join  staging_myuniversity_nit_kkr.users U on U.id = Q.user_id case when Q.college_id = '2' then
    left join  staging_myuniversity_dias.users U on U.id = Q.user_id
    left join  
      ( SELECT  count(id) as id,question_id
            from  just_ask_view 
      ) as V on V.question_id = Q.id
    left join  
      ( SELECT  count(upvote) as upvote,question_id
            from  just_ask_upvote_downvote
            where  upvote = '1'
              and  is_question = '1'
            group by  question_id
      ) as Vote on Vote.question_id = Q.id
    left join  
      ( SELECT  if(count(id) > 0,1,0) as is_upvote,question_id
            from  just_ask_upvote_downvote
            where  upvote = '1'
              and  college_id = '1'
              and  user_id = '1'
              and  is_question = '1'
      ) as Is_Vote on Is_Vote.question_id = Q.id
    where  Q.status = '1'
      and  Q.isDeleted = '0'
      and  case when Q.visibility = 0
      and  Q.college_id != 0 then Q.college_id = '1' else true end
    group by  Q.id
    order by  Q.id desc
    limit  0,30
```

I need to make the join on different databases based on college id 
first i fetch the distinct college id from the question then make a loop 
for college id and try to make join condition but i am getting error there is any suggestion and help

Comment: Can you post the tables you want to combine with sample data?

Comment: Please clean up your code, and simplify it to the minimum needed to solve your problem. Even with a bounty, you shouldn't just dump your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't help you with entire query (I'll just list some concerns), but this "case-join" might be solved with `UNION ALL` subquery this way:

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS college_id, id, firstName, lastName, image
    FROM staging_myuniversity.users
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 AS college_id, id, firstName, lastName, image
    FROM campify_solutions_mathura.users
    UNION ALL
    ...
) AS U ON U.college_id = Q.college_id AND U.id = Q.user_id
```

- When you join counters with subqueries like `SELECT count(), some_id` use `GROUP_BY some_id` as well. Otherwise you'll count all rows in table and join this result for one (first/random) id only (if it passes without error).
- It looks like You use `LEFT JOIN` too much. It means attach to the result on left regardless if any row on the right matches (joins null columns then). It's slow, gives large data sets and results with nulls for most of these columns seems useless.
- Join subquery with `GROUP BY` clause to get concatenated tags
- If large portion of this data will be repeated across the rows (see: N+1 problem) splitting queries (and merging subsets to common "header") might be a good idea.
- Build your query one step at a time. Test subqueries if you're not sure of its results. Start with resource consuming parts - it might get slow at some point and you'll end up splitting it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
... case when Q.college_id = '1' then left join ...
```

does not make sense.  What are you trying to do?

Performance tip:  Don't use `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )`  Instead of that and `IFNULL(...)`, simply do

```
SELECT ...,
    IFNULL(( SELECT ... ), '') AS upvotes,
```

As for pivoting, I must say simply, and strongly, that some tasks are better left to your application code, not SQL.